# Database empty cell IF Statement

Tags: java

When I delete the `else if` part it works fine, but if I keep it, it gives me `java.sql.SQLException: No data found` And obviously I want my String variable get the value from database cell IF the cell wasn't emtpy.

```
String updatedby = ""; // Outside of While loop



// Inside the while loop.
if(rs.getString("UpdatedBy") == null)
{   updatedby = ""; }

else if(rs.getString("UpdatedBy") != null)
{   updatedby = rs.getString("UpdatedBy");  updatedby = updatedby.trim(); }
```

I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just call it once?

```
updatedby = rs.getString("UpdatedBy");
updatedby = (updatedby == null ? "" : updatedby.trim());
```

Less overhead that way. And less code. Cleaner.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. It worked. :)
But why my if statement didn't work? :/

Comment: Don't know. Perhaps a bad JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`ResultSet.wasNull()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull--) which *reports whether the last column read had a value of SQL `NULL`*. Something like

```
updatedBy = rs.getString("UpdatedBy");
if (!rs.wasNull()) {
    updatedBy = updatedBy.trim();
} else {
    updatedBy = "";
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit familiar with `rs.wasNull()` But I thought I had to write the column name inside the parentheses.  Thanks though.